# Is there any way to map values using the column index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python I was trying to automate some processes through pandas.

```
df['x'] = df['ID'].map(df5.set_index('x')['y'])
```

I want to make it generic like:

```
    df['x'] = df['ID'].map(df5.set_index('x')[iloc[:,[5]]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, need seelct 6th column without `[]`:

```
df['x'] = df['ID'].map(df5.set_index('x').iloc[:,5])
```